# array inside model not binding when model is part of an array

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, ajax

So I have a rest API that saves "link" objects. now the rest API for adding "link" object one at a time that binds to the model fine but when its an array of "link" objects being passed it does not bind the List of strings. I have tried both using model that holds an List of Link and Link[].

the model is this

```
public class Link
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "name")]
    public string name { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "fields")]
    public List<string> fields { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "imgPath")]
    public string imgPath { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "category")]
    public string category { get; set; }
}
```

the function in the controller is

```
public string PostLinkList([FromBody] List<Link> links)
    {


        string json;


        bool waiting = true;
        int timeWaiting = 0;
        do
        {
            try
            {
                using (StreamWriter outfile = new StreamWriter("App_Data/linkObjs.txt", false))
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < links.Length; i++)
                    {
                        json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(links[i]);
                        outfile.Write(json + "\n");
                    }

                }
                waiting = false;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                timeWaiting++;
                if (timeWaiting > 20)
                {
                    waiting = false;
                }
            }

        } while (waiting);
        return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(links);
    }
```

The front end looks like this

```
 $(".category").each(function ()
    {
        var tag = $(this).attr("id");
        var category = $(this).find(".issueTitle").children("span").text();
        $("#" + tag + " button").each(function ()
        {
            var imgPath = $(this).children("i").attr("class");
            var fields = $(this).attr("name").split(",");
            var name = $(this).children("p").children("span").text();
            links[i] = {
                name: name,
                fields: fields,
                imgPath: imgPath,
                category: category
            };
            i++;
        });

    });
    $.ajax(
    {

        url: "/api/Link",
        type: "Post",
        async: false,
        contentType:"application/json",
        dataType: "json",
        data: links,
        success: function () { populate(); },
        error: function () { alert("failed to populate"); }
    });
```

Hes what  ,as a string, format looks like/ This is the string passed to the backend

```
"[
{\"name\":\"test name\",
\"fields\":[\"field\",\"details\"],
\"imgPath\":\"optImg icon-print\",
\"category\":\"test\"},
{\"name\":\"test name\",
\"fields\":[\"field\",\"details\"],
\"imgPath\":\"optImg icon-print\",
\"category\":\"test\"},
{\"name\":\"test name\",
\"fields\":[\"field\",\"details\"],
\"imgPath\":\"optImg icon-print\",
\"category\":\"test\"}
]"
```

Comment: can you post your json format?

Comment: sure give me a min

Comment: did you try with data: JSON.stringify(links)

Comment: you mind posting your json array?

Comment: Like the array that is passed or in the file where I store each Link json object.

Comment: @riteshmeher if you want to post an answer i will check it off.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify and use **`json.stringify`**  to serialize the json objects when making the jquery Ajax call.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so found something that fixed it. I had to make a new virtual directory because the updated code was not running. Than the JSON.strigify for sending the links to the back-end with the having a Link[] not list  fix all problems thank you guys for helping. Sorry if i wasted your time.